# What is the correct matrix form for transforming spherical coordinate to Cartesian?

Tags: matrices, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates

While checking online for the conversion of co-ordinate systems, i came across two similar but different matrix form for converting spherical to Cartesian. So which one is correct or are they both the same?

$$\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}A_R\\A_{\theta}\\A_{\phi}\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}\sin\theta\cos\phi&\cos\theta\cos\phi&-\sin\phi\\\sin\theta\sin\phi&\cos\theta\sin\phi&\cos\phi\\\cos\theta&-\sin\phi&0\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}A_x\\A_y\\A_z\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}\sin\theta\cos\phi&\sin\theta\sin\phi&\cos\theta\\\cos\theta\cos\phi&\cos\theta\sin\phi&-\sin\theta\\-\sin\phi&\cos\phi&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A_x\\A_y\\A_z\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$

or

$$\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}A_R\\A_{\theta}\\A_{\phi}\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}\sin\theta\cos\phi&\sin\theta\sin\phi&\cos\theta\\-\cos\theta\cos\phi&\cos\theta\sin\phi&-\sin\theta\\-\sin\phi&\cos\phi&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A_x\\A_y\\A_z\end{bmatrix}\\\begin{bmatrix}A_x\\A_y\\A_z\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}\sin\theta\cos\phi&\cos\theta\cos\phi&-\sin\phi\\\sin\theta\sin\phi&\cos\theta\sin\phi&\cos\phi\\\cos\theta&-\sin\phi&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A_R\\A_{\theta}\\A_{\phi}\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$

Comment: Huh?  They show the same formula (easy to see for going from $(A_x,A_y,A_z)$ to $(A_r,A_\theta,a_\phi)$ and the opposite way is given by the matrix you are taking inverse of on the top line in the first and the matrix in the second equation of the second image.

Comment: I guess the main problem Bolo Morawo faced is the fact the in the second given transform the $\cos\theta\cos\phi$ term has a negative sign infront of it. As far as I can see this is the only difference.

Comment: Yes the cosθcosϕ is what i really want to inquire about but i didn't want to reference the picture directly in the question heading. So why are the signs different?